# # 5 times, where each sentence is separated by a single space

Tags: python

why is this wrong. I do not understand it

> Write a function called `show_excitement` where the string `"I am super excited for this course!"` is returned exactly 5 times, where each
> sentence is separated by a single space. Return the string with
> "return". You can only have the string once in your code. Don't just
> copy/paste it 5 times into a single variable!

```py
str= "I am super excited for this course!"

for x in range(5):
    str =  str + " "
    print(str)
```

Comment: `(str + " ")*5` creates the desired string.

Comment: You are updating the value of `str` each time the loop occurs, and printing it out. The first loop will give "I am... this course! ", and then the second loop will print it out twice. Moving the print to outside the loop will fix that, but there will be a trailing whitespace. In addition, if `str` has to be returned, it should be returned not printed out.

Comment: Naming a variable `str` is a bad idea, don't do it.

Answer (score 4):

give single space at the end of the string

```
return "I am super excited for this course! "*5
```

Comment: How is this an improvement to the main answer?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you'd probably want `str.join`

```
def show_excitement():
    return ' '.join(['I am super excited for this course!'] * 5)
```

Example

```
>>> show_excitement()
'I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course!'
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest way to do that

```
def show_excitement():
    # Your code goes here!
    string="I am super excited for this course! " *5 
    return string

print show_excitement()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
 def show_excitement():
        s=""
        # Your code goes here!
        for i in range(0,5):
            s+='I am super excited for this course!'+" "
        return s
    
    print show_excitement()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
def show_excitement(str,n):
    global result
    if(n==0):
        return result.strip()
    else:
        result=result+" "+str
        return show_excitement(str,n-1)


result = ""
str="I am super excited for this course!"
print show_excitement(str,5)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
def show_excitement():
  string = "I am super excited for this course! "
  return "\"{} {} {} {}{}\".".format(string,string,string,string,string)
    
print(show_excitement())
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post